# On $\Bbb R^2$, Are unit circle centred at the origin and the origin homotopic equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I guess these two spaces are not homotopic equivalent.

I suppose there are homotopic equivalent.
Let $X=\{x \in \Bbb R^2 : ||x||=1\}$

$Y=\{(0,0)\}$

And there exists two functions $f: X\to \{(0,0)\} $

$g: \{(0,0)\} \to X$ such that 
$f\circ g \cong I_d$ and $g\circ f \cong I_d$

since $f: X\to \{(0,0)\}  $ so $f\equiv 0 $
Hence we get $g\circ f(x) =g(0)$ which is homotopic to $I_d(x)$ for any x on X.

Then I claim the winding number of $I_d(x)$ on $X$ is 1 while the $g(0)$ has 0 winding number. Thus I get contradiction. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, every curve is homotopic to the origin, since you can smoothly deform any curve to a point curve - there are no "snags" in the space that stop you from doing this.

Comment: If $0$ denotes the zero map  , then $g \circ f \cong I_d \cong 0$ on that unit circle as long as $g, f$ continuous?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean - the unit circle is _itself_ homotopic to the origin because I can continuously deform any curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$. What do you mean "on that unit circle"?